# Heroku can't find setup.py?

Tags: python, heroku

I have the following dir setup.

```
.
├── setup.py
├── src
│   └── mymodule 
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── database.py
│       ├── models.py
│       ├── parallel.py
│       └── utils.py
└── venv
    ├── bin
    │   ├── activate
    │   ├── activate.csh
    │   ├── activate.fish
    │   ├── activate_this.py
    │   ├── coverage
    │   ├── easy_install
    ....
```

with the following setup.py:

```
setup(
    name='mymodule',
    version='0.1.0',
    install_requires=[],  # Don't put anything here, just use requirements.txt
    packages=['mymodule'],
    package_dir={'mymodule': 'src/mymodule'},
)
```

with requirements.txt:

```
Flask==0.9
...
wsgiref==0.1.2
-e .
```

When I deploy on heroku, I get the error that heroku 'cant find mymodule.database'.

I tried running python setup.py on my local computer in the virtual env (i removed the egg myself to ensure the validity of my setup) and everything seems to work fine.

How can I tell heroku to run `python setup.py install` ? I thought `-e .` is supposed to do that for me already

Comment: What command exactly are you running when you write: "tried running python setup.py on my local computer in the virtual env (i removed the egg myself to ensure the validity of my setup) and everything seems to work fine."  Are you using the requirements file?

Comment: @DavidS oh no I am not. I just run `python setup.py install` and then `python -c 'import mymodule'; print mymodule`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Heroku does the following for you.  Creates a new virtualenv, clones your source from the git repo, then does a pip install -r requirements.txt.  So, my suggestion is to try and do that on your machine.  Once you get it working there, then it should work fine on Heroku.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I also can't get heroku to run my setup.py file

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you have the appropriate structure to run a python app on heroku.
Please review: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python
and see examples of heroku flask scaffolds on github. eg: https://github.com/zachwill/flask_heroku to get a better idea of how things should be set up.  Once you get a hang of how to setup python apps in heroku, you can test locally using the foreman tool described in the heroku docs.